How would I go about creating both a listener thread and client-server functions in the same socket
class Client(server_client_data.Connection):
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        super().__init__(host, port, "Client", None)
        self.socket.connect((host, port))
        self.socket = socketH(self.socket)
        self.logged_in = False
        self.socket.underlying_socket.setblocking(False)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.expecting_data = False

    @staticmethod
    def client_method(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with self.lock:
                self.expecting_data = True
                self.socket.underlying_socket.setblocking(True)

                try:
                    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    self.expecting_data = False
                    self.socket.underlying_socket.setblocking(False)

            return result

        return wrapper

    @client_method
    def login(self, email: str, password: str):
        # writing command
        self.socket.write_string(server_client_data.SERVER_COMMANDS.login.value)
        self.read_exception()

        self.socket.write_string(email)
        self.socket.write_string(password)

        self.read_exception()

        username = self.socket.read_string()
        user_code = self.socket.read_string()

        self.logged_in = True
        return username, user_code

    @client_method
    def log_out(self):
        # writing command
        self.socket.write_string(server_client_data.SERVER_COMMANDS.logout.value)
        self.read_exception()

        self.logged_in = False

    @client_method
    def sign_up(self, email: str, password: str, username: str):
        # writing command
        self.socket.write_string(server_client_data.SERVER_COMMANDS.sign_up.value)
        self.read_exception()

        self.socket.write_string(email)
        self.socket.write_string(username)
        self.socket.write_string(password)

        self.read_exception()

    @client_method
    def send_message(self, message: str, username: str, user_code: str):
        # writing command
        self.socket.write_string(server_client_data.SERVER_COMMANDS.send_message.value)
        self.read_exception()

        # check if logged
        self.read_exception()
        self.logged_in = True

        self.socket.write_bool(False)
        self.socket.write_string(username)
        self.socket.write_string(user_code)

        self.read_exception()

        # write name/title
        self.socket.write_string("empty test")
        # write file validation
        self.socket.write_bool(False)
        # write message
        self.socket.write_string(message)

        # check if sending or creating the message was a successes
        self.read_exception()

        # returns message id
        return self.socket.read_string()

    def start_listener(self):
        stop_event = threading.Event()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.listener_loop, args=(stop_event,))
        self.threads[stop_event] = thread
        thread.start()

    def listener_loop(self, stop_event):
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            with self.lock:
                if not self.expecting_data:
                    try:
                        client_command = self.socket.read_string()
                        if client_command:
                            print(
                                f"Client {self.socket.underlying_socket.getpeername()} initiated the {client_command} command"
                            )
                    except BlockingIOError:
                        continue
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Listener loop encountered an error: {e}")
                        break

    def read_exception(self):
        code = self.socket.read_byte()

        if code < 0:
            raise ValueError(self.socket.read_string())

the code above details a client class that contains both a listener loop and several client functions. I'm in need of a way to create the listener loop in such a way that it won't interfere with my client functions, so it won't read anything when the client function is expecting the input instead.
my current setup doesn't work as I would like, to be honest, I have no idea what is causing the problem, but sometimes it reads data when it shouldn't.
any advice?
a code example of a fixed or working version of my code

This is not an [mcve]. What imports are used and what 3rd party modules are installed?

Just to be clear (and not that I would know the answer) but, are you asking whether there is some way to interrupt the listener loop's client_command=self.socket.read_string() call?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Ohm'sLawman, exactly, what I need is a system where recv is non-blocking in an efficient way that I could interrupt it whenever I need to. My current system kind of works, but sometimes it seems that the loop picks up unwanted data after the function is done, maybe it's a problem with the server, I honestly don't know, just wanted some feedback whatever it might be a known issue or just me being dumb.

This is an extended comment, not an answer:

FYI, this is virtually always* a Bad Idea:
while someTestThatAlmostAlwaysReturnsTrue():
    with self.lock:
        doStuff()

This same pattern is a Bad Idea in most programming languages and operating systems. The reason why it's bad is, each time around the loop, the very next thing that happens after the thread releases the lock is, the thread re-acquires the lock. Even if ten other threads are all asleep, waiting to acquire the lock, it's most likely that the calling thread, which already is awake and running, will be the one that gets it next.
Once any thread gets in to a loop like this, it becomes very hard for any other thread to acquire the lock.
This also is a Bad Idea:
with self.lock:
    callAnyBlockingFunction()

You never want any of your program's threads to hold a lock while it's waiting for something. It doesn't make sense to prevent threads B, C, D, and E from doing any work just because thread A is waiting for some work to do.
Your program appears to do both of those Bad Things.

* The one case where it might not be a bad idea is if doStuff() calls c.wait(), and c was obtained prior to entering the loop by calling c=threading.Condition(self.lock). Calling c.wait() saves you from doing either of the above-mentioned Bad Things because it unlocks the lock while it is waiting, and then it re-locks the lock before it returns.
